# Remove words starting with '$' from string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have input strings of the following format:

```
100-avg:system.cpu.idle{podservice:example,$PodFunction,$Colour,$Environment,$Region} by {host}
```

I would like to convert it into the following format:

```
100-avg:system.cpu.idle{podservice:example} by {host}
```

The variables preceded by the '$' are placeholders. It is possible for there to be more than one valid variable (one without a dollar sign and with a colon and a value). I would also like to remove excessive commas from within the parenthesis.

Since there is no space between the words, I wasn't able to use split by whitespace. Any suggestion would be useful. Thank you

Comment: Split them by `,`. Can you please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've choosen an approach, where I define a function which takes a match of a regular expression (looking for curly brackets) as input parameter and converts the list of comma seperated values in a new list of comma seperated values. On the fly it kicks out values starting with a `$`.

For the replacement process I use `re.sub()` and use the function as parameter. So for each match (every string within curly brackets), the function processes the string inbetween.

```
import re

def process_string(match):
    tmp_string = match.group()
    return ",".join([s for s in tmp_string.split(",") if not s.startswith("$")])

test_string = 'system.cpu.idle{podservice:example,$PodFunction,$Colour,$Environment,$Region} by {host}'

out_string = re.sub(r"(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})", process_string, test_string)
print(out_string)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
system.cpu.idle{podservice:example} by {host}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Tried with multiple valid parameters as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a word start with **$** as below:

```py
import re

str = "100-avg:system.cpu.idle{podservice:example,$PodFunction,$Colour,$Environment,$Region} by {host}"
str = re.sub(r"\$\w+[,]|\$\w+|[,]\$\w+", "", str)
```

The result will be like so `100-avg:system.cpu.idle{podservice:example} by {host}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
for i in re.finditer('\$(.*?)[,\}]',text):    
    unwanted_string = i.group(1) #Capture the string between $ and ','
    text = text.replace(unwanted_string,'') # Replace above string with blank
    text = text.replace(',$','') # Replace the left over $ and ',' with blank
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.